# Update Data of a parent by his child

Tags: ios, objective-c

Sorry if the title is not really clear, I will explain it here anyway.

I've got 2 files: *SelectPostIt.xib* and *PostIt.xib* . 
On my *main.storyboard* i've got a *UIButton* which, when someone push it, it create a new *SelectPostIt*. This one is non editable.

The principle is that when I doubleTap a `selectPostIt`, a new `PostIt` appears:

```
-(IBAction)doubleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {

if(!_isEdited){
    _isEdited = true;

    PostIt *editPostIt = nil;
    NSArray *objects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"PostIt" owner:self options:nil];

    for (id object in objects)
    {
        if ([object isKindOfClass:[PostIt class]])
        {
            editPostIt = object;
        }
    }

    editPostIt.frame = CGRectMake(10,10, 400, 400);
    [editPostIt setParent:self];
    [self.superview addSubview:editPostIt];
}}
```

So normally, the selectPostIt is seated as Parent of the the new Post it in:  `[editPostIt setParent:self];` , right? I already have (in PostIt.m):

```
-(void)setParent:(SelectPostIt*)value{
  _parent = value;
}
```

With a `property(weak, nonatomic) SelectPostIt* parent;`in my PostIt.h.

And then, when I double tap on the *PostIt*, it will disappear but also change the value of the SelectPostIt who created him with this method:

```
-(IBAction)doubleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer{

NSString *string = [self.titre text];
//NSLog(@"string: %@", string );
[_parent setTitre:string];

string = [self.commentaire text];
//NSLog(@"string: %@", stringFromTextField );
[_parent setCommentaire:string];

[_parent setIsEdited:true];

if(_parent == NULL)
    NSLog(@"Pas de parents" );
if(_parent == nil)
    NSLog(@"Pas de parents" );

[self removeFromSuperview];
}
```

I made some test and the String are good but, the value of the *SelectPostIt* aren't changed (the good point is that the *PostIt* disappear at least haha).

So if someone could help me on where I am wrong it could be nice, thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not the exact answer but that's a point I think I must dig on:

I've added in my *PostIt.m*: 
    @synthesize parent;

And changed :
    [parent setIsEdited:true]

To : (that was a mistake from me here)
    [parent setIsEdited:false]

So now, my *PostIt.m* 's doubleTap method looks like:

```
-(IBAction)doubleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer{

NSString *string = [self.titre text];    
[parent setTitre:string];

string = [self.commentaire text];
[parent setCommentaire:string];

[parent setIsEdited:false];
[self removeFromSuperview]; }
```

And from now, when I close a *editPostIt* , when I doubleTap on the *selectPostIt* a new *editPostIt* is created, and I wasn't able to before. That's mean that the boolean from the *selectPostIt* has been changed by the closure of the *editPostIt* .

So I think from now that, this is good:

```
-(IBAction)doubleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer{

NSString *string = [self.titre text];    
[parent setTitre:string]; 

string = [self.commentaire text];
[parent setCommentaire:string];

[parent setIsEdited:false];  
[self removeFromSuperview]; }
```

But I need to "reload" (?) the *selectPostIt* or something else so it could take the new data? I dont really know...